# HTML Fridge Magnet Tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have been searching how to get it done for quite some time but it hasn't helped.

**What are these called, and how are they created in HTML/Javascript ?** I used to call them fridge magnet tags - but I don't think it is the correct name for this input field.

[image]

The tags must come up as soon as one starts typing with suggestions neatly stacked in a dropdown menu. How do I create this ? Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459832/html-form-text-input-suggestions-box

Comment: I think you mean a [typeahead search](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), I'm not sure of the name for layout of the results.

Comment: @Frederik.L This has the autocomplete feature, but I don't think multiple tags can be added.

Comment: See https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Comment: _"I used to call them fridge magnet tags"_ - I don't care what other name it has, this is probably the best :)

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the best option to be used as fridge-magnet tagging widget.

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

*Tag-it is a simple and configurable tag editing widget with autocomplete support.*