# css - Make stackexchange like tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a textbox, that has spans inside it, similar to the ones here, but I'm stuck - I have no idea what to do. The code itself doesn't work. My code:

```
$(".writetags").each(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.bind("keyup", function() {
            elem.data("oldVal", $(this).data("newVal") || "");
            elem.data("newVal", $(this).val());
            var oldVal = elem.data("oldVal");
            var newVal = $(this).val();
            var newChar = newVal.charAt(newVal.length-1);
            var oldChar = oldVal.charAt(oldVal.length-1);
            if(newChar!=oldChar){
                if(newChar==","){
                    var at = 0;
                    if(newVal.lastIndexOf("</span>")>=0){
                        at = newVal.lastIndexOf("</span>");
                    }
                    var toSpan = newVal.substring(at, newVal.length-1);
                    var newTxt = newVal.substring(0, at)+"<span class=\"id\">"+toSpan+"</span>";
                    elem.val(newTxt);
                }   
            }
        }); 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="writetags" id="tags" style="width: 95%;direction:rtl;font-size: 18px;"/>
```

```js
$(".writetags").each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.bind("keyup", function() {
    elem.data("oldVal", $(this).data("newVal") || "");
    elem.data("newVal", $(this).val());
    var oldVal = elem.data("oldVal");
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    var newChar = newVal.charAt(newVal.length - 1);
    var oldChar = oldVal.charAt(oldVal.length - 1);
    if (newChar != oldChar) {
      if (newChar == ",") {
        var at = 0;
        if (newVal.lastIndexOf("</span>") >= 0) {
          at = newVal.lastIndexOf("</span>");
        }
        var toSpan = newVal.substring(at, newVal.length - 1);
        var newTxt = newVal.substring(0, at) + "<span class=\"id\">" + toSpan + "</span>";
        elem.val(newTxt); //change to HTML
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="writetags" id="tags" style="width: 95%;font-size: 18px;" placeholder="Seperate tags using commas." />
```

This doesn't work properly as you can see in the snippet above. Not only it doesn't show the spans, if you type `tag1, tag2,` instead of making it `<span...>tag1</span><span...>tag2</span>` it writes `<span class="id">tag1<span class="id"></span>tag2</span>`

I had an idea of making it work with a div with spans and shorten the input by the new span's length but I have no idea of how to do that and I'd rather keep it simple.

Thanks in advance, NonameSL

Comment: Thats not how SO tagging actually works. If you'd have bothered to check the HTML you would see that the textarea simply shrinks _next_ to newly added span tags. Have a look at how this works on SO by simply inspecting the element and take inspiration from that.

Comment: See https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it , http://stackoverflow.com/tags ; related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401250/html-fridge-magnet-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add external libraries then [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) will be very useful for you. Check the API documentation. It is as simple as

```
// initialize the selectize control
var $select = $('select').selectize(options);
```

See the JS Fiddle for an example, http://jsfiddle.net/MuEh5/

Answer (score 3):

You cannot append anything to an `input` element, as it's a self-closing element. So are the `<img>` or `<br>` elements. This means they only use one tag, to be created, and they cannot have children. The solution would be to create an input and position the tags above it.

Comment: Okay, but if I do that I have to shorten the textbox each time and I don't know how to do that. Can you help me with that? Also, how would I calculate the length of the span?

Comment: You need to calculate only one length - the length of space _remaining_ after adding the `span`. Basically, the wrappers width minus any spans `innerWidth`, and any spacing you are using.

Comment: The easiest thing to do, would be to actually inspect the functionality you want to mimic. For better or for worse, everything front end developers make and share, becomes open-source.